# SELECT DISTINCT ON in SAS PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

How can I select ALL ROWS and where A ROW is existent more then once, (based on ID) just take one (doesn't matter which one).

So I have:

```
ID name val
===========
1 | aa | 32
2 | aa | 32
3 | ad | 32
3 | zy | 11
4 | rr | 21
5 | oi | 44
5 | df | 11
```

result should be

```
ID name val
===========
1 | aa | 32
2 | aa | 32
3 | zy | 11
4 | rr | 21
5 | df | 11
```

It doesn't matter if     `5 | df | 11`   or     `5 | oi | 44` is taken.

On Postgres, `SELECT DISTINCT ON ID` would be my choice.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does it *have* to be done using SQL?  SQL is not really suited to this kind of task.  SAS provides other ways to do it which are much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way to do it will be using Proc Sort:

```
PROC SORT DATA=HAVE OUT=WANT NODUPKEY;
BY ID;
RUN;
```

Otherwise if it is presorted, then @Reeza's solution is nice.
If you have to use Proc SQL, then an undomented feature may need to be implemented: monotonic():

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WANT AS
SELECT * FROM HAVE
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MONOTONIC()=MIN(MONOTONIC());
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

A SAS data step answer,  using First/Last processing

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id;
 run;
```

Comment: Your previous SQL answer worked nicely, as I'm new to SQL, could you explain me, why the `MAX()` function in the String works in combination with `GROUP BY`? Actually this gave me a great solution and improvement for my project! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

With proc sql:

```
proc sql;

select id, max(name) as maxName, val
from work.table
group by id, val;
```